# How to toggle Modal once I receive the props inside Modal.jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Modal Component , Where currently Modal opens and closes once user click on the button , I am submitting a form , and form props are passed to Modal component .

> Is there any way I can toggle Modal once it receive the props
>   `this.props.wrongAnswer` from the Parent Component ?

```
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

<div className={className}>

    { this.props.wrongAnswers.length > 0 ? (

      <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal}>

            <h4 className="padding-bottom-top blue">Total: {this.props.total} Out of 10</h4>

                {this.props.total !== 10 ?

                <h5 className="padding-bottom">Wrong Answers :</h5>

                :

                <h5>All Answers are Correct</h5>} {asnwersData}

      </Modal>) : 

    (<div> Loading ..</div>)
}
</div>
```

Modal is recieveing props like :

```
          <div> 
             <ShowModal
                total={Total}
                wrongAnswers={wrongAnswersByUser}
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Compare your nextProps with the current props if it's received changes so then `setState` open to true

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.wrongAnswer !== nextProps.wrongAnswer) {
        this.setState({open: true});
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I did an example on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/yw1zvnvn2x)

Comment: When I do that nothing changes at all ?

Comment: Please make sure you're receiving a changes from `this.props.wrongAnswer` do something like `console.log(this.props.wrongAnswer, 'check this')`

Comment: Got it working , there is a typo in your answer `this.props.wrongAnswers` notice extra `s` Thanks Man !!

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. Anyway I updated my answer with example